# Implement interface with ASM: ClassCastException

Tags: java, class, java-bytecode-asm

I'm writing an application which requires the dynamic implementation of an interface. I had no (obvious) issues regarding generating the class: I verified it with both javap and a decompiler.

The problem is, after I generate the class I define and instantiate. Finally, I cast it to the type of the implemented interface.

The problem is that I am being hit with a `java.lang.ClassCastException: MyGeneratedClass cannot be cast to MyInterface`, though I do add `MyInterface` as an interface when I call `ClassWriter.visit`.

Below is an SSCCE demonstrating the issue for an interface named `MyInterface` full of void methods.

```
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);

cw.visit(V1_6,
        ACC_PUBLIC | ACC_SUPER,
        "MyGeneratedClass",
        null,
        "java/lang/Object",
        new String[]{MyInterface.class.getName().replace(".", "/"});

{
    MethodVisitor mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
    mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL,
            "java/lang/Object",
            "<init>",
            "()V");
    mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
    mv.visitMaxs(0, 0);
    mv.visitEnd();
}

for (Method call : MyInterface.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    MethodVisitor mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, call.getName(), Type.getMethodDescriptor(call),  null, null);
    // ...
    mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
    mv.visitMaxs(0, 0);
    mv.visitEnd();
}
cw.visitEnd();
byte[] raw = cw.toByteArray();

try {
    return (MyInterface) new ClassLoader() {
        public Class defineClass(byte[] bytes) {
            return super.defineClass("MyGeneratedClass", bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        }
    }.defineClass(raw).newInstance();
} catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Printing out the `generatedObject.getClass().getInterfaces()` does indeed show that `MyInterface` is implemented. But `generatedObject instanceof MyInterface` returns false, something which I find a contradiction.

Can anyone shed some light on whats happening here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd guess it's because the new classloader isn't a child of the classloader that loaded `MyInterface`, which means you end up with two different classes which aren't the same despite being to all appearances identical. Try changing

```
return (MyInterface) new ClassLoader() {
```

to

```
return (MyInterface) new ClassLoader(MyInterface.class.getClassLoader()) {
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. Looking back it seems glaringly obvious that the class wouldn't be visible to the system classloader. Thanks again!

Comment: Remember: a class is defined by it's FQCN and the classloader it came from!